I would mark b) as wrong. Why isn't it "will"?
My question is about the use of "would" when speaker B answers A's question. Can you explain why "will" is not used in B's response?

A: Choose the best option for the sentence:
We .... have time to help you tomorrow.
a. may
b. must
c. will
d. could
The answer is c). But I think a) is still possible. Can you give it a
check?
B: I would mark (b) as wrong, and (d) as possible but unlikely.

Why does speaker B reply "would“ instead of "will"?

Asking to find errors is off-topic on this site. You say you would mark B as wrong, but you haven't even said why. If you do some personal research into the answer but are still confused then you may be able to make a more suitable, specific question on a point of learning English.

"I would say", "I would think" are often used when expressing an opinion, so as to sound more polite. Rather than saying "This is the fact", the speaker implies "If I had to give my opinion, I would say that this is the fact". See this question.

@KateBunting I mean why not say "I will mark B as wrong?" Or I will say and I will think. This makes me confused

@Astralbee I mean Why does speaker B not say "I will mark B as wrong?" I'm always confused

"I will [do something]" means you are going to do it in the future, which isn't what B  means. They are using the convention I have just explained -  "[If I was the teacher marking this exercise] I would mark (B) as wrong..."

"We .... have time to help you tomorrow." could have several different modal verbs depending on the intended meaning. Either this is a bad question (quite likely) or you're not giving the full context.

It depends on context. Even B could be right in some circumstances, particularly if you slightly change the wording to "We must make / find time to help you tomorrow." Even the original  "We must have …" with emphasis on must implies "Whatever else we are doing tomorrow, surely we will be able  find the time to help you." Often expressed as a question to others involved.

@PeterJennings Sorry, my question regarding the use of "would"  when B answers A's question. B uses "would', can you explain why use "would" rather than "will?" Why doesn't B just say "I will mark B as wrong?"

@KateBunting Well, can you give an example sentence when we use "I will ..." in this situation so that it's clear for me?

A is definitely a possible answer. The difference between A and C is the certainty expressed.

"I don't have time to mark your test paper today; I will mark it  tomorrow."

OP's query is clear: My question is about the use of "would" when speaker B answers A's question. Can you explain why not use "will" in a B's response? He is not asking to solve the multiple choice but explain the reaction of the speaker B to. Speaker A and use of would instead of "will" in Speaker B's reaction.

@MasturohEdna You can edit your question to bring clarity : **"I am not asking answer to the choices question. But about the statement by Examiner 2/ Professor 2. Why had he used would instead of will. I too missed your opening lines and thought you were asking the correct choice and whether B's answer is correct. When I read the comments I read the question with more attention.

OP's query: Why does speaker B reply "would“ instead of "will"?

Examiner: I "would" mark (b) as wrong, and (d) as possible but unlikely.

I used the term examiner for clarity, as using Speaker B with  option b) may create ambiguity.
The sentence can be understood as hypothetical, reflecting a Second Conditional structure:
If I were to evaluate, I "would" mark (b) as wrong..
[Since no one has answered yet, the situation remains hypothetical.]
Also, "would" sounds more polite than "will."
It softens the statement and shows that the examiner is giving an opinion instead of making a strong or firm judgment.

The question:
Which of these bolded words is correct?

We may/must/will/could have time to help you tomorrow.

The answer:
Context, context, context!
This is a classic example of the principle that often a word choice is not between the right or wrong word, because it depends on the intended meaning. All of the above options will be correct if the setting is right. For example:

I'm not sure. We may have time to help you tomorrow, but I need to check with my wife first.

We must have time to help you tomorrow. Your project is vitally important, so even if we have other things scheduled, we will cancel them and be sure to be there.

We have finished painting our house and have a couple of free days. So we will have time to help you tomorrow. Definitely.

Our parents are visiting tomorrow, but we don't know when they will arrive. Depending on how that works out, we could have time to help you tomorrow.


